# Is there an equivalent to an RSA UFO in lattice-based cryptography?

Tags: rsa, lattice-crypto

So there's this concept within the realm of RSA cryptography called an [RSA UFO](https://ethresear.ch/t/generating-rsa-ufos/3401). It is an extremely important function in the context of cryptocurrency. When starting up a cryptocurrency the creator(s) need an initial cryptographic setup. Worst case scenario an untrustworthy initiator uses the startup information to wreak havoc on the cryptocurrency. Its better to have a number of people collectively create the startup information, but you still can't trust them. An RSA UFO allows the creation of the initial cryptography in such a way that even the creator doesn't know the initial values; trustless setup of a cryptocurrency.

Lately with all the fuss about quantum-safe cryptography, especially lattice-based cryptography, I was just wondering if a functional equivalent to an RSA UFO exists in the realm of lattice-based cryptography.

Answer (score 2):

According to your link, RSA UFO means:

> Random moduli are also called RSA UFOs (Unkown Factorisation Objects).

If the definition of an RSA UFO is a modulus generated so that no one knows the factorization, this issue does obviously not exist in lattice-based cryptography, since the factorization problem is never used there. More generally, it is much easier to securely and distributively generate the random parameters of various cryptographic constructions in lattice-based cryptography; distributively and securely generating an RSA modulus with unknown factorisation is a notoriously very hard problem, whose solutions are usually quite inefficient (the link you give ends up with a modulus of total size 81kbits, which is quite huge). In contrast, public parameters in lattice-based cryptography will in general just need to be primes and some public random matrix, which is easy to generate securely and efficiently.

Comment: I interpreted OPs question to be asking if it is possible to generate a public key for a lattice-based scheme in a untrusted distributed manner rather than generating public parameters for the scheme.

Comment: Well its not distributed, but you are partially correct. My question is that can a trustless setup of cryptographic primitives be achieved in lattice-based cryptography without the use of trusted individuals to create them.